# Error al añadir una nueva tupla a Array en Firebase. Expected type 'fc', but it was: a custom an object

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firestore

Buenas estoy intentando añadir una nueva tupla a mi matriz en Firestore.

[image: Datos Firestore]

He estado mirando documentación y he encontrado como hacerlo pero me da un mensaje de error y no consigo averiguar como arreglarlo.

Este es el código que uso:

El documento.id lo coge correctamente, error está al hacer el **updateDoc** y no es problema del async y await. nombre1 y avatar1, ambos son string.

`const docAct = doc(db,"lobbys",documento.id);`
`await updateDoc(docAct,{nombre: arrayUnion({nombre1,avatar1})});`

También probé:

`await updateDoc(docAct,{nombre: arrayUnion({"name":nombre1,"avatar":avatar1})});`

Este es el error que sale:

`Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'fc', but it was: a custom an object`

Espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

const data = [...datag, nombre: {"name":nombre1,"avatar":avatar1}]

await setDoc(doc(db,"lobbys",documento.id),{ data})

espero que te pueda ayudar

Comment: No funciona Jackson. Me sale el siguiente error:

```FirebaseError: Function setDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom nh object (found in field nombre in document lobbys/0nk3XqXw4RPVGIrmuI6l)```

Comment: si ya me di cuenta hay la modifique ve a ver si te sirve

Comment: Sale el mismo error. Creo que lo puse correctamente como me dijiste:

```await setDoc(doc(db,"lobbys",documento.id), {nombre: arrayUnion([{"name":"David","avatar":"Avatares/Avatar12.png"},{"name":nombre1,"avatar":avatar1}])})```

Comment: prueba orita a ver

Comment: También lo probé y nada, mismo error

Comment: Además de colocar código, debes explicar brevemente su funcionamiento. La respuesta debe ser útil y entendible no solo para el OP (autor de la pregunta), sino también para los demás quienes tengan un problema similar. Lee [answer].

Comment: datag es la data que esta guardada en firebase

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres hacer, pero no me deja pone el nombre de la coleccion nombre:{..} dentro del array. Y cuando lo hago sin poner el nombre de la coleccion me da un error diciendome que debe ser un objeto pero que le he pasado un array

Comment: bueno pasalo asi como te lo modifique  como un objeto a ver si te sirve

Comment: Esa si me sirvió. Si quieres explicarlo un poco más para la gente que tenga este problema, tipo que debes poner los datos anteriores y demás. Muchas graciaas

Comment: ok mucha  suerte